# 5 tosses of a fair coin with a few conditions

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

When a coin is tossed 5 times, tails comes up exactly 3 times, the first and last tosses come up tails or the second and fourth tosses come up as heads.

My understanding is that this question has 3 parts all ORed.

1. 3 tails in 5 tosses: P = 10/32
2. First and last come up as tails: 3 blank spots means 2*2*2 = 8 possibilities, so P = 8/32
3. Second and 4th are tails: this time again 3 blank spots so again, P = 8/32
   Adding all of it, I get 26/32.

But answer is given as 9/16 (Refer to question 2 in the below link)

[Answer given as 9/16](http://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~demmel/ma55_Fall07/Exams/Barkauskas_Final_Review.pdf)

Please let me know where I'm making the mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use inclusion exclusion to get rid of double-counting.

\begin{align}
P(1 \cup 2 \cup 3)
&= P(1) + P(2) + P(3) - P(1 \cap 2) - P(1 \cap 3) - P(2 \cap 3) + P(1 \cap 2 \cap 3)\\
&= \frac{10}{32} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4} - \frac{3}{32} - \frac{3}{32} - \frac{1}{16} + 0\\
&= \frac{18}{32} = \frac{9}{16}.
\end{align}

Comment: Oh yes, thanks. I missed that part.

Comment: You have put P(1 intersection 3) as 3/32. Shouldn't it be 1/32?

Comment: @aste123 $P(1 \cap 2)=P(1 \cap 3)$. In both cases, two of the tails are fixed, and there are three choices for where the third tail is.

Comment: Actually the question in the pdf is different from the one I put up in the details. So, answer shouldn't be 9/16. But the method is same inclusion-exclusion principle. I will modify the question and accept the answer.